# What does this means in this context ? それならそれでもいい /sore nara sore de mo ii

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english, video-games

**Context: MC is living with 3 big sisters (春姉 is the eldest big sister, 冬花 is his 2nd big sister, and 夏希 is his 3rd/the youngest big sister). Now he's trying to hide the fact that he and his 2nd big sister had kissed each other last night.**

**Appreciates if anyone can explain to me correctly this part "それならそれでもいい" meaning.
(my guess : "If you says so, then I'll temporarily believe that's the truth" ? - no subject here so it's hard for my JP level to understand 100% ><)**

冬花 (His 2nd Big Sister)「夏希と何かあったんだ？」

疾風 (MC)「うっ、別に何でもないよ」

残された俺をじぃ～っと見つめながら問いかけてくる冬姉だったが、さすがに本当のこと……。

夏姉とキスしてしまったなどと言える訳もなく、何でもないよ、の一点張りで押し通す。

冬花「あたしと春姉に言えないようなこと？」

疾風「いや、だから夏姉の言った通り、何にもないよ」

冬花「まあ、**それならそれでもいい**けど、春姉と違って、あたし、結構しつこいよ？」

Answer (score 1):

The phrase それならそれでもいい basically means something like *"if it's that, then that's okay too"*.  What the "it" is depends on the context of the overall conversation.